# How to use Gnuplot Preview extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gnuplot

The [Gnuplot Preview extension](https://github.com/0xfizzy/vscode-gnuplot) allows us to preview the plot generated by the gnu script.  The guide says:

```
Just open your gnuplot script and use command gnuplot.view.
```

I would like to ask where I can run this `gnuplot.view` command.  I have tried the terminal but that didn't work.

Comment: I don't see yet the advantage of using such an interface (maybe syntax highlighting). Why don't you save your script, e.g. as `'myScript.gp'`, start the gnuplot console and type `load 'myScript.gp'`. If you are using an interactive terminal, e.g. like `wxt` or `qt`, you will see the image immediately. You can e.g zoom in and save it as png, pdf, svg. However, if you set a PNG or PDF terminal you need a viewer for this format which does not block overwriting/updating open files. Worst case, you have to do a refresh on that viewer and you see your updated image.

Comment: It is convenient, but not much more than calling `gnuplot` on my script.  Anyways, I am just trying to figure out where that `gnuplot.view` command can be called from.